# Elantech touchpad: right button OR two-finger scroll

Tags: touchpad, asus, multi-touch, button, elantech

Dear Ubuntu community,

I recently bought an AsusPro PU401LA laptop (FreeDOS, wiped by Ubuntu 13.10).
It ships with a regular Elantech touchpad, i.e. it has physical left and right buttons.
I would like to use *both* the physical buttons and two-finger scrolling.

Out of the box, the touchpad was detected as a PS2 input device (according to xinput), so it lacked multitouch. I updated to kernel version 3.13, but still no multitouch.

I managed to activate multitouch features using [this dkms package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/comments/137). I can use two-finger scroll, right-bottom area click or two-finger click to substitute the right button. However, I would like to use the existing physical right button. The problem is that the package above disables the right button of my touchpad. `xinput` now results in the following:

```
 Virtual core pointer                       id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

`xinput list-props 12` yields:

```
...    
Synaptics Capabilities (589):   1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
...
```

That is, the right button is not detected anymore.
I can alternate between the right button and multitouch features, but I cannot have both right now.

Could you help please?